# How Can I Add Dynamic HTML Attributes in MVC 5 using EditorFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have been working on making an extension method for an MVC 5 site.  The basic idea is that it will create the markup for our input groups (ie. put in the label, inputs and validation messages).  These groups will have some standard HTML and CSS classes that will always be present.  So far this is what I have and it is working fine.

```
public static MvcHtmlString CreateEditorForGroup<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    TagBuilder editorLabel = new TagBuilder("span");
    editorLabel.AddCssClass("form-label");
    editorLabel.InnerHtml += helper.LabelFor(expression);

    TagBuilder wrappingDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
    wrappingDiv.InnerHtml = editorLabel.ToString() + helper.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }}).ToString() + helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString();
    return new MvcHtmlString(wrappingDiv.ToString());
}
```

I also need to extend this a bit farther to allow a additional custom HTML attributes to be passed in (additional CSS classes, data attributes, etc).  So I got this far:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CreateEditorForGroup<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributesForEditor = null)
{
    TagBuilder editorLabel = new TagBuilder("span");
    editorLabel.AddCssClass("form-label");
    editorLabel.InnerHtml += helper.LabelFor(expression);

    var editorHtmlAttributes = MergeHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributesForEditor, new { @class = "form-control" });

    TagBuilder wrappingDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
    wrappingDiv.InnerHtml = editorLabel.ToString() + helper.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = editorHtmlAttributes }).ToString() + helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression);
    return new MvcHtmlString(wrappingDiv.ToString());
}
```

(Don't worry about the definition of `MergeHtmlAttributes`.  Currently it works fine and returns `IDictionary<string, object>`.)  Since all the research I had done (and my own testing) shows that I can do the following

```
helper.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
```

and get the expected result (in my case, a textbox with a css class "form-control").  But if I use the code that merges the attributes, I don't get anything different than if I had called `EditorFor` without the second argument (ie. my textbox comes out without any CSS classes set).

So I have tried some other things, like casting the merged attributes to an `object`.  No change.  I tried converting the merged attributes to an `ExpandoObject`.  Nothing.  Tried casting the `ExpandoObject` to an `object` before passing it in.  No difference.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  It seems weird that this only works with anonymous types while most of the other methods (`TextBoxFor`, etc) can take a dictionary of attributes.

(The only thing I can think of at this point is to start rewriting / overriding the default templates to accommodate this somehow.  I'd rather not go down that road if I don't have to.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change htmlAttributes from anonymous to RouteValueDictionary

Try something like this:

```
RouteValueDictionary htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(editorHtmlAttributes);
... + helper.EditorFor(expression, new { htmlAttributes = htmlAttributes }).ToString() + ...
```

Comment: Why would a RouteValueDictionary make a difference?  This has nothing to do with routing at all.

Comment: If you read that article, it states that in MVC 5.1 they fixed the problem I was having by adding the ability to use the anonymous object the way I was using it.  With that fix they happened to use a RouteValueDictionary (which, as the article admits, is a horrible name once the uses for it expanded).  But as of MVC 5, the only way to accomplish this was to override the default templates.  So your solution doesn't actually fix the problem in MVC 5.  The "solution" in that case would be to upgrade to MVC 5.1 or higher.